# Firebase Hosting Cannot access to my localhost:5000 created by firebase serve from Android emulator

Tags: android, firebase-hosting

I can access my localhost from the Genymotion Android Emulator but when it comes to accessing the port that the `firebase serve` opened, it fails.

By typing `10.0.3.2` into browser in my android emulator I can go to localhost main menu which is Appserv.
After typing the command `firebase serve`, it says me that your files are being served on `localhost:5000`. When I type it(`10.0.3.2:5000`), it simply does not work.

I am looking forward to any help.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

To access your localhost through Genymotion is using machine IP address. To get machine's IP address go to:

```
start -> cmd -> ipconfig
```

Then search for IPv4, copy the IP and paste it in your URL. It should looks like the following:

```
String MAIN_URL = "http://192.168.0.1:5000/";
```

Hope this works for you, give me a feedback.

Comment: Thanks for answer first. However, this also what i tried. While I can access 192.168.x.x, it fails when I try to go to 192.168.x.x:5000

Comment: are you try with AVD? @Ziya ERKOC

Comment: I have problem with AVD but I tried with a real device as well as Genymotion

Comment: refer this 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator
@Ziya ERKOC

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator
@Ziya ERKOC Is this Work For you ?